# Task.Run vs Task.WhenAll vs Parallel.Invoke vs others: Run tasks in parallel and Get result in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is the code in Option 1 below the best way to achieve in running tasks in parallel?

**Option 1**

```
var w = Task.Run(async () => await Work1());
var w2 = Task.Run(async () => await Work2());
Console.WriteLine("end: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
await w;
await w2;
Console.WriteLine("last: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " " + w.Result + " " + w2.Result);
Console.WriteLine("end");
```

**Result:**

```
end: 06:07:13.054
Work2 s 06:07:13.057
Work1 s 06:07:13.057
Work1 e 06:07:16.072
Work2 e 06:07:17.066
last: 06:07:17.066 1 2
```

**option 2:** 
It swithes to other work upon await, ie. not really in parallel.

```
            var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
            tasks.Add(Work1());
            tasks.Add(Work2());
            Console.WriteLine("end: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            Console.WriteLine("end2: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
            Console.WriteLine("last: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " " + tasks[0].Result + " " + tasks[1].Result);
```

**Result:**

```
Work1 s 06:11:42.565
Work2 s 06:11:44.571
Work1 e 06:11:45.579
end: 06:11:47.572
Work2 e 06:11:48.574
end2: 06:11:48.575
last: 06:11:48.579 1 2
```

Tasks

```
  private static async Task<int> Work1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Work1 s " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Work1 e " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
            return 1;
        }

        private static async Task<int> Work2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Work2 s " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Work2 e " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
            return 2;
        }
```

Parallel.Invoke() doesn't return result.

Answer (score 2):

`Parallel.Invoke()` accepts `params Action[]` that mean you need to pass an list, if to be more accurate - array of actions, action to it. In simpler words you need to pass a method to execute. Simply invoking `Parallel.Invoke()` wont do a thing.

Here is an example from [Parallel tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/parallel-invoke)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    static void Test2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test2");
    }

    static void Test3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test3");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(Test, Test2, Test3);
        Console.WriteLine("[INTERMEDIATE]");
        Parallel.Invoke(Test, Test2, Test3);
    }
}
```

After reading more carefull your question, more thoughs came to my head.
What if you tried to use `Parallel.ForEach()` ?

It probably could look something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(tasks, task =>{
var result = task.Invoke();
//You can do whatever you want with result
});
```

Assuming that `tasks` is `List<Task<int>>`, if to be more precise - `IEnumerable<Task<int>>`, of tasks that you need to perform.

Comment: I need to test it. But it seems `Parallel.ForEach` and `task.Invoke` could work. However, i need to log different message for each result of CRUD. For example, create for the first result, update for the second result, and so on. Thus, my option 1 seems easier, because each task is assigned to a variable.

Comment: You can always extend code base. Since `task` is an `action` you can post inside brackets missing code or you could apply AOP ( aspect oriented programming ) or Proxy Pattern. You could have a method who would have `logStartTime` and `logEndTime` and in between task execution. What do you think ?
But I guess it's out of scope of this question. Overall if you find my answer helpful in anyway please mark as accepted, mate.